# Unexpected lifetime of lambda in pipeline

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, range-v3

I'm using a pipeline of ranges views and I want to do a complete transformation of the output and keep the pipeline going. I understand that I can't return a copy of the new range because it wouldn't live anywhere. What I don't understand is why I can't keep the storage in the lambda's closure.

```
auto counter = []() {
    std::map<int, int> counts;
    return ranges::make_pipeable([=](auto &&rng) mutable -> std::map<int, int>& {
        // Do stuff that fills in the map
        return counts;
    });
};

auto steps = foo() | counter() | bar();
auto data = // stuff
ranges::for_each(data | steps, [](auto &&i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
});
```

When I do a release build this works, but when I do a debug build this segfaults. If I change the `map` in the `counter` lambda to be static and the capture to be by reference then this works of course (but is clearly ugly as anything).

What I don't really understand is why the lifetime of the lambda returned from `counter` (and it's attendant closure) isn't at least as long as the lifetime of the variable `steps`.

Comment: Try Valgrind to check the root of crash.

Comment: When I debug this the crash is in the map iterators, this is what I'd expect if the map was already destructed and the iterators outlive it. I can get a better stack trace, but not right now

Comment: Returning a reference from an exited lambda is use-after-free.

Comment: Is it though? I think it isn't because the closure's lifetime should be tied to the lifetime of the lambda. If I return a reference to a captured variable that's fine so long as I don't use it after the lambda goes out of scope, and the question revolves around the lambda. Why isn't the lifetime of the lambda the same as the lifetime of steps?

Comment: `counts` is owned by the lambda and it's invalid as soon as it exits.

Comment: Can you tell me why? Which lambda are you referring to? Note that it is captured by value in the lambda that is returned by `counter` so is part of that closure.

Comment: Sorry, seems you are right. Nevermind my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took @skgbanga's code and re-wrote it so it works more like the actual situation. This shows that the application of the steps to the data results in extra copies of the lambdas captured by the pipeline.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>


struct Noisy {
    Noisy() { local_ = ++cnt_; std::cout << "Noisy() ctor " << local_ << '\n'; }
    Noisy(const Noisy&) { local_= ++cnt_; std::cout << "Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor " << local_ << '\n'; }
    Noisy(Noisy&&) { local_ = ++cnt_; std::cout << "Move constructor " << local_ << '\n'; }
    ~Noisy() { std::cout << "~Noisy() dtor with local " << local_ << '\n'; }

    // global object counter
    static int cnt_;

    // local count idx
    int local_ = 0;

    // Make this a range as well. Empty is fine
    std::vector<int> range;
    auto begin() { return range.begin(); }
    auto end() { return range.end(); }
};
int Noisy::cnt_ = 0;


auto counter = []() {
    Noisy n;
    return ranges::make_pipeable([=](auto x) mutable -> Noisy& {
        std::cout << "Returning Noisy range " << n.local_ << '\n';
        return n;
    });
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto steps = counter();
    std::vector<int> data{{1, 2}};
    std::cout << "Applying" << '\n';
    auto result = data | steps;
    std::cout << "Displaying" << '\n';
    ranges::for_each(result, [](auto&& v) {
        std::cout << "Local result " << v << '\n';
    });
    std::cout << "Deleting" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Noisy() ctor 1
Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor 2
Move constructor 3
Move constructor 4
~Noisy() dtor with local 3
~Noisy() dtor with local 2
~Noisy() dtor with local 1
Applying
Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor 5
Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor 6
Returning Noisy range 6
~Noisy() dtor with local 6
Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor 7
~Noisy() dtor with local 5
Displaying
Deleting
~Noisy() dtor with local 7
~Noisy() dtor with local 4
```

Noisy 6 is the one that returns the range and because it was a copy used in the evaluation of the pipe it is almost immediately destructed. This then causes the segfault.

I expect that the extra copies shouldn't really happen.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `make_pipeable` takes it argument by value. Here is the definition from the src code:

```
    struct make_pipeable_fn
    {
        template<typename Fun>
        detail::pipeable_binder<Fun> operator()(Fun fun) const
        {
            return {std::move(fun)};
        }
    };
```

Since you are returning `std::map<int, int>` by reference, it is pointing to an address of an object which has been moved from. (`std::move` in the above call)

If this is not super clear, consider a simpler example. In the below code, Noisy is just a struct which emits out its calls.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/utility/functional.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

struct Noisy
{
   Noisy() { local_ = ++cnt_; std::cout << "Noisy() ctor " << local_ << '\n'; }
   Noisy(const Noisy&) { local_= ++cnt_; std::cout << "Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor " << local_ << '\n'; }
   Noisy(Noisy&&) { local_ = ++cnt_; std::cout << "Move constructor " << local_ << '\n'; }
   ~Noisy() { std::cout << "~Noisy() dtor with local " << local_ << '\n'; }

   // global object counter
   static int cnt_;

   // local count idx
   int local_ = 0;
};
int Noisy::cnt_ = 0;

auto counter = []()
{
   Noisy n;
   return make_pipeable([=](auto x) { return n; });
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   auto steps = counter();
   std::cout << "Deleting" << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is this:

```
Noisy() ctor 1
Noisy(Noisy&) copy ctor 2
Move constructor 3
Move constructor 4
~Noisy() dtor with local 3
~Noisy() dtor with local 2
~Noisy() dtor with local 1
Deleting
~Noisy() dtor with local 4
```

As you can see, object `2` (which in your case is holding the `std::map<int, int>`) is destroyed before the line printing `Deleting`. `steps` is a `pipeable_binder` struct which extends from our passed lambda and is destroyed at the end.

Comment: """As you can see, object 2 (which in your case is holding the std::map<int, int>) is destroyed before the line printing Deleting."""

Actually I think by then it's moved into layer 4 hasn't it? I'll try this myself when I get a chance. I expect that the application of the data to steps will make additional copies of the lambda and that a reference to the value inside one of these shorter lived copies is the problem.

Comment: It has. But you are returning the reference to the map in the object2. And yep.